# Running Console application from ASP.NET

Tags: c#

I want to know how to run my console application from ASP.NET, which is in one solution.

I want to run and stop the application.

Comment: I think you must back away but not slowly (very fast) please.

Answer (score 4):

On a client machine or on the server ?

if you are thinking client machine there is no way !

anyway this is how you do it on the application's server

```
        Var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";//in your case full path with the application name
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = " ";//arguments 
        process.Start();

        // Do your magic here

        process.Kill();//Dont forget to kill it when you are done
```

Comment: This is all nice as long as you can keep process handle between requests somehow (if it runs for a longer time - otherwise I don't see a reason to run a separate process). I'm thinking InProc session to keep handle... But how should one do this when Asp.net app pool gets recycled? How can you control the process in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Just start it like you'd start any normal EXE.

```
var proc = Process.Start(@"C:\myconsole.exe");
```

You should place the console EXE file at a proper place though.

And you can end it with:

```
proc.Kill();
```

...

**Note:** that starting the process on *a single request* might not be a good idea. It might be better to start it on another thread and lets it spin so you can *response* to your users faster.

Comment: On another thread would run it within IIS app pool which may get recycled for any reason. A separate process is more robust but you get to loose process handle... or?